# Desktop gray-out and back to normal

Tags: 12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit desktop (Running on laptop core i7-2670QM CPU with 16GB of Ram, 500 GB (less than 25% in use)).  The problem is, occasionally a window will gray-out and unresponsive (say Libre office, or geany text editor). 10 seconds later, the gray thing disappeared and the application is responsive again.

The CPU is not busy at that moment, I can hear the fan is not blowing very hard. Sometimes, I do have the CPU busy and I can see it from both from "top -c" command and from the sound of fan. Strangely, it didn't cause any gray-out.

Any idea what may be the cause.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for the gray-out (which signals that this one program cannot proceed) is not a general high CPU load but a problem with I/O (this is also known as I/O-Wait).

So when your program tries to write to the disk but for some reason the disk is slow to respond you will get this behavior.